# I have Multiple SQL queries how to store all query results and display it in table form

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have multiple queries like

```
query1=select StudentName from student limit 1;

query2=select StudentAge from student limit 2;
```

I want something like

```
category        value
StudentName    query1 result
StudentAge     query2 result
```

Comment: 'something like' is a bit vague what exactly do you want? And what possible value is there in selecting 1 'random' student and 2 'random' ages?

Comment: I want to store multiple query results in a table

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask add table definitions, sample data and expected outcome to the question as text.

Answer (score 0):

Just to illustrate how far away from a good question you are here's an answer which fully complies with your question but may be absolute rubbish.

```
drop table if exists student;
drop table if exists t;

create table student(id int, studentname varchar(3), studentage int);
create table t(val varchar(4));
insert into student values
(1,'aaa',19),(2,'bbb',19),(3,'ccc',30),(5,'ddd',20);

insert into  t
select * from
(
select StudentName from student limit 1
) a
union all
(
select StudentAge from student limit 2
) ;

select * from t;

+------+
| val  |
+------+
| aaa  |
| 19   |
| 19   |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```